# Mysema QueryDSL how to use "like"?

Tags: java, querydsl

am trying to use boolean builder in this way

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

         builder.and(model.record.Id.eq(Id));
         builder.and(model.record.date.like(date));
```

I want to fetch records with the given date by ignoring the time and hours ,so i want to do a "like". but am getting the following error

> cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   method like(java.util.Date)
>   variable date of type
>   com.mysema.query.types.path.DateTimePath

Somebody help me out how can i use like in mysema?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use LIKE with date fields, if you need to get only the date part of a field you should use the DATE function of Hibernate to ignore the timestamps.

With QueryDSL you can call the DATE function by using the `date` method from the QueryDSL's `SQLExpressions` class.

So, rewriting your query with the solution given above it should look close to his:

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

         builder.and(model.record.Id.eq(Id));
         builder.and(model.record.date.eq.(SQLExpressions.date(date)));
```

Also, please check out this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/MU2p6FoKzgc) to get more info about SQLExpressions.

Good luck and keep us updated with your results!

Comment: Hi, am getting this error while compilation  com."mysema.query.sql does not exist" Am using querydsl version 2.8. also  I understood your query as                                                builder.and(model.record.Id.eq(Id));
         builder.and(model.record.datebasedate.eq.(SQLExpressions.date(inputdate)));

Comment: Try execute your query without the second part of your builder. If it works, then the I really don't know how resolve your problem. Otherwise if the error keep appearing, it's probably a problem unrelated with the first question, and you should open another one so people would be able to help you.

Comment: Without SQLExpressions i.e by removing second condition it's working fine but the second condition is what is need :) proabably the package SQLExpression is not supported in 2.8 , Thanks for your help.